# Convertir variable string a Color en Unity

Tags: unity, color, rgba

Quiero convertir un color a RGB, actualmente recibo un color en RGBA desde un Gameobject, lo almaceno en un string después de convertirlo a RGB.

Lo que no logro es convertir ese string que contiene dentro el color RGB en un tipo **Color**.

```
Color componentColor = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
string colorParseadoRGB = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(componentColor);
```

Estoy tratando de convertir a Color mediante:

```
string color = "#" + colorParseadoRGB;
Color c;
ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(color, out c);
```

El string si me devuelve el color en RGB pero el **Color c me devuelve aún en RGBA**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo tienes que utilizar la función contraria en ColorUtility:

(recuerda añadir el caracter '#' al principio del string representando el color)

```
Color componentColor;
String color = '#' + colorParseadoRGB;
ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString( color, out componentColor );
```

Comment: Cuando hago esto que comentas me devuelve el color en RGBA, no entiendo el motivo, si le hago un debug.log me devuelve RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 0.491, 1.000)